# IP messenger is not showing other computers in same network

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipmsg

HI we are using ipmsg in our office. previously it was working fine but now on one of these computers it has not showing the names of other computers.
Note:
All computers are truned on
network is working
and ipmsg on other computers are showing the name of that computer

only the particular PC is not showing others.
please help

Answer (score 0):

refresh the ip messenger so that you can see all other users in the network **(if other users ip messenger is on).** to on ip messenger double click on ip messenger icon on desktop.

eventhought it not possible to see all the user in network then see your PC is connected other network the step are given below:-

> **Control Panel->Network and Internet->Network and Sharing Center**

you see all the network connection including ethernet. if it is case then disable all network except one network where all users are connected

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when we installed ip messenger and started searching others, without restarting.
1. See that you have installed latest version of IP messenger.
2. Turn off firewall (windows or third party).
3. Restart PC.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on the same problem, however, the solutions here didn't work.
Finally I found a solution as discussed in this thread.

https://groups.google.com/g/ipmsg-bbs-eng/c/LOLlg2ib1zE/m/4EhWJUhkAQAJ

In Basic/LAN settings changing Local segment broadcast to "Both use" immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Re: IP messenger
 1) For this u have to give Static IP (In Network and Sharing Center - Properties - IPv4 Configuration **Disable the DHCP Option** and Assign Static IP address, Subnet mask, Default Gateway)
 2) After IP messenger will Work Properly
For me this issue came i done like this,After it Works Properly,